# Mysql: fetch value from database and php array in single query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

**mixed_menu**

[image: mixed_menu]

```
SELECT mixed.unique_id, 
MENU_LABEL 
      case 
          when (--something...)
FROM mixed_menu mixed 
ORDER BY mixed.position ASC
```

**Question:** I want to write a mysql query which can retrieve unique_id, MENU_LABEL with the following condition.

- CASE1:

  if type == 'db_category' then retrieve **label** from database (**1.db_category**) where id=unique_id
- CASE 2:

  if type == 'category' then retrieve **array value** from php array (**2.PHP Array**) where array key=unique_id

---

**1. db_category**

[image: db_category]

**2. PHP Array**

```
$category_array = array('car'  => 'All Cars', 
                        'jeep' => 'All Jeeps'
                       );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easier if you created a new table with your php array.

But using your current structure, you can create a temporary/fake table like this

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 'car' as `id`, 'All Cars' as `label`
  UNION
  SELECT 'jeep' as `id`, 'All Jeeps' as `label`
) php
```

So, you can use a query like -

```
SELECT mm.unique_id,

CASE
  WHEN mm.type = 'db_category' THEN dbc.label
  WHEN mm.type = 'category' THEN php.label
END as menu_label

FROM mixed_menu mm

LEFT JOIN db_category dbc ON mm.unique_id = dbc.id

LEFT JOIN (
  /*Create fake table*/
  SELECT 'car' as `id`, 'All Cars' as `label`
  UNION
  SELECT 'jeep' as `id`, 'All Jeeps' as `label`
) php ON mm.unique_id = php.id

ORDER BY mm.position ASC
```

here is a SQLFiddle example - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5630cc/5

You would then need to build that fake table using your php array.

**EDIT**

Since your `mixed_menu` and `db_category` tables are `COLLATION latin1_swedish_ci`, and using `SELECT UNION` is defaulting to `COLLATION utf8_general_ci` you will need to declare this in your `SELECT UNION`

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 'car' COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci as `id`, 'All Cars' COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci as `label`
  UNION
  SELECT 'jeep' COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci as `id`, 'All Jeeps' COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci as `label`
) php
```

So now the query would be

```
SELECT mm.unique_id,

CASE
  WHEN mm.type = 'db_category' THEN dbc.label
  WHEN mm.type = 'category' THEN php.label
END as menu_label

FROM mixed_menu mm

LEFT JOIN db_category dbc ON mm.unique_id = dbc.id

LEFT JOIN (
  /*Create fake table*/
  SELECT 'car' COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci as `id`, 'All Cars' COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci as `label`
  UNION
  SELECT 'jeep' COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci as `id`, 'All Jeeps' COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci as `label`
) php ON mm.unique_id = php.id

ORDER BY mm.position ASC
```

Comment: thanks for your fast reply and efforts, i am working on it. shows the error- #1267 - Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'case'

Comment: What is the Collation of `mixed_menu` and `db_category`?

Comment: See the **EDIT** in my answer. You will need to declare the fake table's Collation implicitly -> `SELECT 'car' COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci as `id`,` to match the Collation of `mixed_menu`/`db_category`

Comment: thats great man. So I guess the fake table, i can generate query, using php foreach traversal through the $category_array.